# how to edit an eeg data file?

Tags: matlab, eeglab

i have a file : 30_19.1.20.eeg , which contains eeg data , i want to split this data into two halves . so first i imported the data file to matlab using the following :
i imported a 30_19.1.vhdr file into eeglab using : `file->import data -> using eeg functions and plugins -> from brain vis. Rec.vhdr or ahdr file`

after that i received in the matlab workplace the following :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiDtf.png)

so i want to open the data file so i pressed the EEG struct ,
this is what it contains :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4tUp.png)
and this struct contains a filed called data , when i open it i have a matrix that contains all of the data
basically i want to split this data into half .
how can i do such a thing ?
i tried to change this struct but i always get the following error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bys2Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

Structures are variables which have "sub-variables" called properties inside them, a bit like directory / sub-directory structures.

Assuming the data in your `eeg` variable is called `data`, you can do the following to load the data into a new variable: `m = eeg.data`. If you want to load half of that data, assuming the half is in terms of numbers of rows, then you could write:

```
m = eeg.data(1:floor(size(eeg.data,1)/2),:);
```

Comment: so now i have a new variable with the data i want , but now i want to save the changes that i have done in a new eeg file .. how can i do this ?

Comment: also this variable i think i should replace it with the old variable so everything could work

Comment: yes that is correct. simply update your eeg variable with the new data and save (look in matlab help for the "save" function)

Comment: i still have the same problem , because i still want to save these changes ( which means i want to save the changes in the eeg file so when i open it again i could see these changes ) , but if i press on save i still get the same error , it tells me that i can only save the variable itself , so it would save the variable in a new mat file , and thats not what i want ! i want to update the eeg file itself

Comment: you asked how to extract half of the data from your variable, and the above solution does that. if your question is now how to export an eeg file i do not know how to do that and suggest you read the manual of your eeg software in case it allows importing mat files.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to "select data" from the continuous EEG dataset file. There are 2 options:

- time range in seconds
- point range (one-sample precision)

You have to apply this procedure twice (lower range, higher range) to get the 2 separate files.

After doing so, you can type `EEG.history` in the command window to get the Matlab code that has been executed.

[image]